# Как поменять кодировку файла?

Tags: java

*Есть такая вот задача:*

> В метод main первым параметром приходит имя файла, тело которого в
>   кодировке Windows-1251. В метод main вторым параметром приходит имя
>   файла, в который необходимо записать содержимое первого файла в
>   кодировке UTF-8.

*Мое решение:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    reader.read(buffer);
    String s = new String(buffer, "Windows-1251");
    buffer = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    writer.write(buffer);

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

В результате во втором файле у меня получаются крокозябры. Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Много чего не так. Вот работающий код. Думаю, разберётесь.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Main {

    private final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try (final FileInputStream    fileInputStream    = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
             final InputStreamReader  inputStreamReader  = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "windows-1251");
             final FileOutputStream   fileOutputStream   = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
             final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, "utf-8"))
        {
            final char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int readed;
            while ((readed = inputStreamReader.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                outputStreamWriter.write(buffer, 0, readed);
        }
    }
}
```