# Java. IO. Пробемы с кодировкой при чтении файла

Tags: java, utf-8, unicode, io

У меня вот такой метод читающий файл:

```
        private String fileContent = "";

        void writeFile(String path) {
            try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path)) {
                int stream = input.read();
                while (stream != -1) {
                    this.fileContent = String.format("%s%s", this.fileContent, ((char)stream));
                    stream = input.read();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Когда читаю из файла английский алфавит все ок. Но когда пытаюсь считать кириллицу получаются иероглифы. Хотя в файле с которого я читаю кодировка UTF-8 и в среде разработки у меня UTF-8 стоит. Подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: Вам надо как-то указать что вы хотите UTF-8 читать. Попробуйте тут посмотреть http://stackoverflow.com/a/13350772/3212712

Comment: Недавно отвечал на подобный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/598054/194374

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решил вот так. Может кому-то еще полезно будет. 
Сразу из файла в необходимую кодировку.

```
    private String fileContent = "";
    private void writeFile() {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(this.path), "UTF-8"))) {
            String sub;
            while ((sub = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.fileContent = String.format("%s%s\n", this.fileContent, sub);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если Java version >= 1.7, то можно использовать StandardCharsets: `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: А клево! Спасибо буду иметь в виду.